# how to get input values in enter key press event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to submit a form when press enter without page refresh.

here is my code.

php code.

```
<form action="profile/update_profile" method="post" id="business_name_data">
 <input type="hidden" name="business_name" id="business_name"/>
</form>
```

update_profile function

```
public function update_profile()
{
  json_encode($this->input->post('business_name'),true);
}
```

js code

```
 jQuery(document).keyup(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

    if(e.which == 13){
    jQuery.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url :  "../profile/update_profile",
                    data : "business_name="+jQuery("#business_name").val(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success : function(msg) 
                    {    
                        console.log(msg);
                            //jQuery("div").find(".category_view").html(msg);
                            //jQuery("#1").css("visibility","visible");
                    }
          });
             }
          });
```

I am trying to pass input value.but it prints null.
please help.

Comment: You don't have any value in your input.

Comment: Where is the code that assigns value to `business_name`.?

Comment: I THINK YOU NEED SOMTHING LIKE
<input type="hidden" name="business_name" id="business_name" value= "my_value_here"/>

Comment: if the field is hidden when I click on a text it changed to type="text"

Comment: @IshaS the type of field doesn't matter, $("#id").val() gives value of any input field having id=is whether it is hidden or not

Comment: Do you really want to submit the form when someone hit enter anywhere in the page Or when you are in a visible field?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

You have to set value to hidden element

`<input type="hidden" value="busineesname" name="business_name" id="business_name"/>`

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13){
    jQuery.ajax({
               type : "post",
               url :  "../profile/update_profile",
               data : {"business_name":jQuery("#business_name").val()},
               dataType: "json",
               success : function(msg) 
               {    
                        console.log(msg);
               }
             });
           }
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCNaK/2/)

Comment: Just wondering, how can you call it a demo when it wont function?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger just tell to the OP , function working fine and input params posted

Comment: how to set user input for <input value=""/> insted of value="busineesname" ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first
alert the value in before the if condtion as :

```
alert(jQuery("#business_name").val());// check this if it gives the value
```

and if it gives the value and put `echo` as you have not `echo` or `print_r`

in the update_profile function

```
public function update_profile()
{
   echo json_encode($this->input->post('business_name'),true);
   //add the echo and check  

}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: when I alert(jQuery("#business_name").val()); it has nothing.it was the problem.how can I get input value? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: try this alert($("#business_name").val());  use $ instead of jQuery

Comment: try by putting your code in the $(document).ready(function(){  
 //copy all js code here
})

Comment: Please check for : 1)Whether you have included js file properly 2)Whether the field id `business_name` is duplicate(same id for multiple fields)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to echo the value in your `update_profile()` method

```
public function update_profile()
{
  echo json_encode($this->input->post('business_name'),true);
}
```

Next step is to check if the *Enter Key* is pressed or not try this, also try printing the value from the input field `business_name` to the console to see if it has value or not.

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "../profile/update_profile",
            data: {
                "business_name": jQuery("#business_name").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: when I try to get input value it prints string(0) "" .can't get user input. thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

if you made a mistake and you wanted a visible text box and when you click enter on it you want to submit the form with out refreshing the page you can subscribe to the submit event

```
  $(function(){
      $('#business_name_data').submit(function(event){
        alert('your ajax call');
        event.preventDefault();
      });
   });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tbHTjyRKEV0cxraP3R6n?p=preview